# How do I enable .Net Native on my Application?

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, .net-native

With the recent announcement of .Net compiling to native code, I want to know how can I enable this functionality in my applications?  Does it work for all project types and all platforms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today, .Net Native only supports Windows Store Apps targeting ARM or X64.  In the future other project types and platforms may be supported.

Start by making sure you have the correct tool chain installed.  You need Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2 RC and the Native Developer preview installed on your machine:

- [VS 2013 Update 2 RC](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=393601)
- [.Net Native Developer Preview](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=393600)

After everything is installed, right click on your project and select `Enable for .Net Native`

[image]

After doing this, you should see a new file added to your project `default.rd.xml`.  This is a report that tells you if your application is compatible with .net native code generation.

If everything is compatible, you can enable the compilation in the project properties.  As I mentioned previously, this only works for x64 and ARM platforms at this time, so select one of those platforms and you can check the `Compile with .Net Native tool chain` option:

[image]

I suggest watching this channel 9 video on how the tooling works:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Inside-NET-Native

Comment: default.rd.xml is not really a compatibility report, but a runtime directives file containing directives about what metadata and type information needs to be preserved.

Comment: Who the heck set it by default for vs 2015? I couldn't understand why my project is building so long